# How does ECS Fargate resolve DNS Names? I want to connect my MongoDB Database but can't

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am using Amazon ECS Fargate service to deploy a multi-container application for practice. The application docker image is `kodekloud/ecs-project2`. But I can't connect api with the database.

I created a task definition with 2 containers with these names.

1. `api` (using `kodekloud/ecs-project2` image from docker hub)
2. `mongo` (using `mongo` image from docker hub)

I have exposed the required ports (3000 for api and 27017 for mongo). And I created a volume of Amazon EFS to store the mongodb data.

Now when the `api` tries to connect with the `mongo` container running on ECS Fargate. It simply can't connect to it. I have used the correct Environment variables for both containers. I have deployed it multiple time with different configurations and after checking the logs using CloudWatch everytime, it says couldn't connect with MongoDB. (The application `api` is configured to output this if it fails and then exit with error code 1)

I have tried localhost for connecting with mongodb. And I also have tried `mongo` after using service connect but still i can't run my app. If there is a need to give more info then i can give. Please note that i doing this thing for the first time.

Comment: With both containers running in the same task, on Fargate, `localhost` should have worked. You should also try `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Thanks @MarkB but I think I should create separate Services for Both Backend API and MongoDB Database and connect them using Service Connect. Is this approach good?

Comment: That's a completely separate question. In general I do not recommend running any database servers at all on ECS Fargate, because the persistent storage available (EFS) is too slow. I recommend running your stateless services on Fargate, and either using AWS Document DB or MongoDB Atlas for your database.